# how to load spring-boot based REST application properties from a different file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It seems the spring-boot launcher looks for `application.{xml|properties|yml|yaml}` file in the following locations to load properties. Is there a way to specify a different filename or file to load properties from?

```
$ java -Ddebug -jar target/app-1.0.jar
16 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.properties' resource not found
16 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.yaml' resource not found
16 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.yml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.properties' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.xml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yaml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.properties' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.xml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.yaml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.yml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'file:./application.properties' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'file:./application.xml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'file:./application.yaml' resource not found
32 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'file:./application.yml' resource not found
6 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener  - Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.xml' resource not found
```

**EDIT**:

Is there a way to specify another Bean configuration file (like application-context.xml)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to load the properties.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = {"yourProperties.xml"})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the folder where springs searches for the configuration file during startup.

`java -jar target/app-1.0.jar -Dspring.config.location=your/config/dir/`

Comment: Note - To use a non-standard file name, that would need to be combined with `spring.config.name`.

Answer (score 1):

In command line you can use below property to mention an additional boot configuration file:

```
--spring.config.name="file:/path/to/application.properties"
```

An alternative would be:

```
-Dspring.config.name="file:/path/to/application.properties"
```

Note that characters are lower case and the word separator is a period **.**.

Otherwise you can use an environment variable with key you used already:

- In a *nix system:

  ```
  export SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=file:/path/to/application.properties
  ```
- In Windows OS:

  ```
  set SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=file:/path/to/application.properties
  ```

*More on **Spring Boot Configuration** in [following Docs resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).*